# How to split a string without removing the delimiter?

Tags: python, regex

I know this question has already been answered in the past. But I am however still encountering difficulties, although I have tried applying multiple suggestions I found online. So, what I want is quite easy. Split this string

```
"__label__2:somedata"
```

or

```
"__label__43:somedata"
```

and get

```
['__label__2:', 'somedata']
```

or

```
['__label__43:', 'somedata'].
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import re
line = "__label__2:somedata"
p = re.split("(__label__{1,2}:)", line)
print (p)
```

But this unfortunately prints

```
['__label__2:somedata']
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you could use a simple `split()`. It removes the delimiter, but you know that it is supposed to be between all the parts of your string, so you could just add it afterwards

Comment: Try: "(__label__\d{1,2}:)" You are missing a \d

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh no I don't know what number is supposed to be inside the delimiter. Here it is 2 and 43, but it could be 989 etc...

Comment: If more than 2 digits do: "(__label__\d+:)"

Comment: you know what it's supposed to be, otherwise you can't perform the `split` operation

Comment: @cehalon798  you misunderstand the point of the simple split suggestion. It would not matter what the number was. If you split on colon then the results would be the text before the colon and the text after the colon. You could simply append the colon to the first result, as needed. Anyhow, the `\d+` solution is probably better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add \d+ inside your regular expression, like so:

```
(__label__\d+:)
```

This also allows you to capture all numericals rather than having to list all possible values...

Answer (score 0):

`"(__label__{1,2}:)"` is not doing what you think. `{1,2}` is requesting 1 or 2 repeats of the `__label__` string, **not** the characters `1` or `2`.

The correct syntax is using `[12]`:

```
import re

re.split('(__label__[12]:)', "__label__2:somedata")
```

output: `['', '__label__2:', 'somedata']`

If you want to split after any `__label__`+digit+`:` use `\d+`, also slice to remove the first empty string:

```
>>> re.split('(__label__\d+:)', "__label__789:somedata")[1:]
['__label__789:', 'somedata']
```

Comment: This doesn't generalise as you've hard-coded the numbers after `__label__`. I believe OP was enumerating using `{1,2}`, albeit enumerating the wrong thing.

Comment: @navneethc I'll add an update, but my goal was to address the major issue, which was an incorrect use of the regex syntax

Comment: `{1,2}` in `(__label__{1,2}:)` requires the first underscore after `'label'` to be followed by one or two underscores. One would need `(?:__label__){1,2}` to match one or two instances of `':__label__'`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to hesitate between spliting the string and matching a part of it. Both are possible but they are different and have different use cases.

1. split:

   You have just to split on `:` and add the delimiter to all parts but the last:

   ```
    lst = line.split(':')
    mx = len(lst) - 1
    result = [ s if i == mx else s + ':' for i, s in enumerate(lst)]
   ```
2. match:

   You have to match the first part and, separately, the rest of the line:

   ```
    m = re.match('(__label__\\d{1,2}:)(.*)', line)
    resul = m.groups()
   ```

You will split if you can expect to have more than 2 fields, and match if you want to control the pattern of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> s="__label__2:somedata"
>>> t=s.partition(':')
>>> [t[0]+t[1], t[2]]
['__label__2:', 'somedata']
```

If you have a bunch, you can use a comprehension:

```
cases=("__label__2:somedata", "__label__43:somedata" )

>>> [[t[0]+t[1], t[2]] for t in map(lambda s: s.partition(':'), cases)]
[['__label__2:', 'somedata'], ['__label__43:', 'somedata']]
```